# Netplan - bridge default spanning tree behavior

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, netplan, network-bridge

I'm not a Linux noob, but this is my first post on Ask Ubuntu.
If I am missing any key information, please let me know and I'll update the question.

```
OS: Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 x86_64
Kernel: 5.15.0-48-generic
All packages are up to date.
```

I've observed that Spanning Tree Protocol is not being enabled by default for network bridges configured with Netplan, despite the manual indicating it should be the default behavior.

Furthermore, the 'stp: true' entry to enable it in the netplan yaml is being rejected when running 'netplan apply'.

I have successfully set up my network by modifying /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: false
    enxb2e5f92d03ca:
      dhcp4: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      interfaces:
        - enxb2e5f92d03ca
        - enp1s0
```

However I've confirmed that stp is not being enabled with:

```
<host>:~$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.4231c3cca58e       no              enp1s0
                                                        enxb2e5f92d03ca
```

If I enable stp manually:

```
<host>:~$ brctl stp br0 on
```

STP turns on and all is well... until I reboot and STP resets to disabled again...

```
<host>:~$ brctl show
    bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
    br0             8000.4231c3cca58e       yes             enp1s0
                                                            enxb2e5f92d03ca
```

I'm trying to get STP to be enabled by default for my network bridge.

Other than the manual describing that is should be on by default, I've also tried adding the stp parameter to the above yaml:

```
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      stp: true
      interfaces:
        - enxb2e5f92d03ca
        - enp1s0
```

However this gives me an error as follows:

```
Error in network definition: unknown key 'stp'
```

The manual also describes an 'rstp' parameter (not sure what it does), but this is rejected similarly to above.

I am aware that yaml is very sensitive to line spacing, but I cannot tell if I am formatting it poorly, or if there's something wrong with netplan. (it's probably my syntax though)

Any advice would be appreciated. I just need STP enabled by default.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My file is normally this:

```
doug@s19:~/config/etc/netplan$ cat 01-netcfg.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [ enp3s0 ]
      dhcp4: yes
#      dhcp4: no
#      addresses: [192.168.111.136/24]
#      gateway4: 192.168.111.1
#      nameservers:
#        addresses: [192.168.111.1]
#      dhcp6: no
#      link-local: [ ]
#      parameters:
#        stp: true
#        forward-delay: 4
```

Resulting in this:

```
doug@s19:~/config/etc/netplan$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.3c7c3f0d9983       no              enp3s0
```

I did this:

```
doug@s19:~/config/etc/netplan$ cat 01-netcfg.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [ enp3s0 ]
      dhcp4: yes
#      dhcp4: no
#      addresses: [192.168.111.136/24]
#      gateway4: 192.168.111.1
#      nameservers:
#        addresses: [192.168.111.1]
#      dhcp6: no
      link-local: [ ]
      parameters:
        stp: true
#        forward-delay: 4
```

resulting in this, after re-boot:

```
doug@s19:~/config/etc/netplan$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.3c7c3f0d9983       yes             enp3s0
```

I did not try to isolate things further:

```
doug@s19:~/config/etc/netplan$ diff 01-netcfg.yaml.doug 01-netcfg.yaml.test
19,21c19,21
< #      link-local: [ ]
< #      parameters:
< #        stp: true
---
>       link-local: [ ]
>       parameters:
>         stp: true
```

Comment: Your example is exactly what I needed. I didn't have a 'parameters:' section, which is why it wasn't accepting the 'stp: true' line in my yaml.
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I have opened bug here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/2007304